# Where do I see Testcafe Studio console log errors?

Tags: testing, logging, console, message, testcafe

Where do you read console log messages in testcafe studio?

I am writing this code;

```
 var image  = await getImageElement(
   Selector('.call-to-action__image'
 ).nth(1).nth(1).nth(1).find('a').find('img'));

 console.log(image.src);
 console.log(image.alt);
 await t.debug()
   .expect(isEmpty(image.src)).eql(true,"Ribbon does not exist")
   .expect(isEmpty(image.alt)).eql(false,"Ribbon does not exist");
```

This code is for trying to read which value of src or alt the element gets.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

At this moment, you can not read the `console.log` messages in TestCafe Studio. However, you can get the `console.log` result in your terminal if you run your testfile using the TestCafe Open Source.

Please read the following article to get more details about installation and running TestCafe Open Source: 
https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/installing-testcafe.html